# Unable to change the div color dynamically using VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I am developing an application using Bootstrap and VueJS.

I am developing a Google drive like folder structure, wherein I want to highlight a div in blue when it is selected.

Here is the code:

```js
export default{
  mounted(){  
    $(document).ready(function () {

      let that = this;
      $("#div").on("click", ".folderRectangle", function () {
          $(that).css("background-color", "blue");
          $(".folderRectangle").not(that).css("background-color", "white");
      }); 
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.folderRectangle { 
  x: 220px; 
  y: 473px; 
  width: 299px; 
  height: 62px; 
  background-color: #FFFFFF; 
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD; 
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <stats-card>
      <div slot="header" class="folderRectangle" id="div">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="clearfix">

              <i class="material-icons" id="folder-image">&#xe2c9;</i>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="clearfix" style="position: relative">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left">Folder Name</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align:left">20 files</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </stats-card>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <stats-card>
      <div slot="header" class="folderRectangle" id="div">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <i class="material-icons" id="folder-image">&#xe2c9;</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="clearfix" style="position: relative">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left">Folder Name</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align:left">20 files</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </stats-card>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

When I try clicking on the div, I am unable to change the css color of the div using onClick. What wrong am I doing? Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Don't put a jQuery `$(document).ready()` handler in your `mounted` hook; it will never run because the document was _ready_ a long time before your component was mounted

Comment: So should I just have $("#div").on("click", ".folderRectangle", function () {})?

Comment: Could you please explain how I can do this?

Comment: You can use the VueJS.com website. [VueJS - Class and Style bindings](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example i provide you a basic example using [`Class bindinng`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) and when you select an elements will be highlighted in blue :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
    return {
      selected: -1,


      folders: [{
          name: "Folder 1",
          numFiles: 25
        },
        {
          name: "Folder 2",
          numFiles: 20
        },
        {
          name: "Folder 3",
          numFiles: 21
        }, {
          name: "Folder 4",
          numFiles: 20
        }


      ]


    }
  },
  methods: {



  }

})
```

```css
.folderRectangle {
  width: 299px;
  height: 62px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.folder-selected {
  background: #4545ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="app" class="row">



  <div slot="header" class="folderRectangle" v-for="(folder,index) in folders" @click="selected=index" :class="{'folder-selected':selected==index}">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="clearfix">

          <i class="material-icons" id="folder-image">&#xe2c9;</i>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <div class="clearfix" style="position: relative">
          <div>
            <p style="text-align: left">{{folder.name}}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p style="text-align:left">{{folder.numFiles}} files</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How does this work with OP's `<stats-card>` components?

Answer (score 2):

The way you're approaching this isn't very *Vue-like*. I also wouldn't recommend mixing jQuery and Vue but that's more of a personal choice.

The way to do this with Vue would be to have your component *emit* an event on click which the parent can use to communicate to the other `stats-card` components that they should change the colour.

You can keep track of each card using [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

For example...

```js
Vue.component('StatsCard', {
  props: { isActive: Boolean },
  template: `<div :class="{active: isActive}" @click="handleClick">
  <slot></slot>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    handleClick () {
      this.$emit('click', this)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeCard: null
  },
  methods: {
    setActiveCard(card) {
      this.activeCard = card
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.folderRectangle { 
  width: 299px; 
  height: 62px; 
  background-color: #FFFFFF; 
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD; 
  background-color: white;
}

.active .folderRectangle {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <stats-card @click="setActiveCard" ref="card1"
              :is-active="activeCard === $refs.card1">
    <div class="folderRectangle">Content #1</div>
  </stats-card>
  <stats-card @click="setActiveCard" ref="card2"
              :is-active="activeCard === $refs.card2">
    <div class="folderRectangle">Content #2</div>
  </stats-card>
</div>
```